# Comparing suffering of humans to people from higher realm

Tags: reference-request, suffering, realms

In the story of Prince Nanda, He equal the most beautiful female humen on earth to a died monkey as compared with a women from higher realm.

Lord Buddha said that The king of all earth is like a beggar in the heaven.

Are there more other detailed comparisons between humens and people from higher realms ?

I'm asking this because, I don't feel much suffer about this life. Life is going ok. But, If we compare the typical humen life to the life in heven, This is lot of suffering. Because, People of heavens doesn't need to do hard jobs. Some of them don't do any job. Brahmas don't get hungry. So, Having a better understanding of higher realms may helpful to understand suffering of this world.To avoid pursing physical things (Because richest/luckiest/happiest person is nothing compared to the heaven, most valuable thing/achievement is nothing compared to the heaven)

Kind regards.

Comment: Not even compareable, pleasure and lifespan, good householder, as if a human watches a bug or marggot, a fly. So easy to finde objets to observe to get a little taste Wanna go after dung further? Sure, a bug, ant... isn't aware of human realm even right around.

Comment: Even higher and gain-able right here and now: "Sole dominion over the earth,
going to heaven,
lordship over all worlds:
 the fruit of [stream-entry](https://sangham.net/en/lib/study/into_the_stream)
 excels them."

Comment: I feel your ideas are too anthropomorphic and too various to deal with easily. I would just say that if you delve more deeply then you can expect most of these questions to fade away, to be replaced by a few even harder ones.

Comment: Answers, please. This is a Q&A site.

Comment: Some people are suffering because they have no food to eat. Some other people suffer because their home WiFi doesn't reach the toilet. I suppose it's something like that. (Can I write this as a [zen-style answer](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1561/471)?)

Comment: This is a [tag:reference-request] question -- the OP is asking for references.